# assign label names while looping in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vue and I have a table. I want to re-use for other views so that I am trying to make it as a component. I will be parsing data and the column names and I want to create the table dynamically according to data(queriedData) and column names.

Following code works fine:

```
<md-table-row slot="md-table-row" slot-scope="{ item }">
   <md-table-cell md-label="Member" >{{item.id }}</md-table-cell>
   <md-table-cell md-label="First Name" md-sort-by="firstName">{{item.firstName }}</md-table-cell>
   <md-table-cell md-label="Last Name" md-sort-by="lastName">{{item.lastName}}</md-table-cell>
   <md-table-cell md-label="Institute">{{item.institute}}</md-table-cell>
   <md-table-cell md-label="Age Group">10-12</md-table-cell>
   <md-table-cell md-label="Level">Novice</md-table-cell>
   <md-table-cell md-label="Status">{{ item.status }}</md-table-cell>
</md-table-row>
```

and it gives following output:

[image]

However, because of this is a component, I don't want to hardcode fields. I am trying to generate them dynamically as follows:

```
 <md-table-row v-for="(item, rowIndex) in queriedData" :key="rowIndex" :md-item="item">
    <md-table-cell v-for="(column, indexColumn) in columns" :key="indexColumn">
       {{ item[column] }}
</md-table-row>
```

This gives an output something like this:

[image]

*My problem is this. In the second method table headers/ labels are missing, I do not know how to specify **md-label** for each cell. I tried to do `md-label={{column}}` but it did not work.*

Answer (score 0):

```js
<md-table-row v-for="(item, rowIndex) in queriedData" :key="rowIndex" :md-item="item">
    <md-table-cell v-for="(column, indexColumn) in columns" :key="indexColumn">
       {{ item[column] }}
</md-table-row>
```

i don't see `Scoped Slots` in your new table anymore. After rendered from first table codes, the cells doesn't have `data-label` or such. I would suggest to wrap your like Basic Table as below (that's if you keen to go with your method)

```html
  <md-table>
      <md-table-row> <!--THEAD-->
        <md-table-head md-numeric>ID</md-table-head>
        <md-table-head>Name</md-table-head>
        <md-table-head>Email</md-table-head>
        <md-table-head>Gender</md-table-head>
        <md-table-head>Job Title</md-table-head>
      </md-table-row>
.
.
.
. //WRAP YOUR LOOP TABLE-ROW HERE.
  </md-table-row>
</md-table>
```

Lastly, please let us know which framework you using other than *just Vue*, since took me awhile to figure you're using `Vue Material` (since there're tonnes of frameworks out there, and expect someone to bump in)